# How to reset ComboBox scrolling position in JavaFX?

Tags: javafx, scroll, combobox, reset

I created a comboBox with a long list and a button to reverse the alphabetical order of this list.

The problem is that if I scroll down to a certain point of the list and then I click on the button to reverse the list order, the list is correctly reversed and displayed, however the comboBox doesn't start from the top, but it starts from the previous scrolling position.

E.g., If my list is "A, B, C, ..., Z" and I scroll my combo until the i-th element, let's say M, when I reverse the order, the list shown in the combo is "Z, ..., C, B, A", but it doesn't start from Z: it is still positioned at the i-th element.

How to reset this "scrolling issue"?

Here's my code:

```
@FXML
private ImageView ascOrder, descOrder;

@FXML
private ComboBox<String> expNameCombo;

ascOrder.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
     @Override
     public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
        ascOrder.setVisible(false);
        descOrder.setVisible(true);
                
        //populate the combo in descending order
        expNameCombo.getItems().clear();
                
        for (Experiment exp : ClientHttps.getInstance().getExperiments().descendingSet()) {
            expNameCombo.getItems().add(exp.getName());
        }
                
    }
});
        
descOrder.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {             
    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
        descOrder.setVisible(false);
        ascOrder.setVisible(true);
                
        //populate the combo in ascending order
        expNameCombo.getItems().clear();
        for (Experiment exp : ClientHttps.getInstance().getExperiments()) {
            expNameCombo.getItems().add(exp.getName());
        }       
    }
});
```

Comment: Big hack, but maybe `((ListView<String>)expNameCombo.lookup(".list-view")).scrollTo(0);` works?

Comment: Maybe you can add `expNameCombo.getSelectionModel().selectFirst()` just after sorting items

Comment: @0009laH hmm .. good idea, are you sure that selection scrolls the selected into view? Faintly remember having seen a bug report (might be fixed, though)

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Comment: an alternativ - though not cleaner - way (instead of lookup as suggested by @James_D) to grab the list is from the combo's skin: `combo.getSkin().getPopupContent()` .. which points the way to a clean solution: implement your own combo plus skin having scrollTo methods :)

Comment: @kleopatra Yes you're right, I've had that problem with JavaFX 8 u192, I've never tried with newer versions

Comment: @James_D unfortunately you solution doesn't work, it triggers a nullPointerException: Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "javafx.scene.control.ListView.scrollTo(int)" because the return value of "javafx.scene.control.ComboBox.lookup(String)" is null

Comment: @0009laH unfortunately you solution selects the first item of the list, so it appears in the comboBox text like it has been selected by the user, but the list is still located at the point where it was before the sorting